# Testing your code for multiple browsers using phpunit & php-webdrivers by facebook

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

I am working with php-webdrivers by facebook for selenium to implement integration testing for my site. I am using phphunit to run my tests and have wrapped my code inside the phpunitframework_testcase extended class:

```
class WebTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @var \RemoteWebDriver
     */
    protected $driver;
    protected $url='http://example.com';
    protected $screenShotDirectoryPath  =   '/screenshots/';


    /**
     * @BeforeMethod
     */
    protected function setUp()
    {
        try{
            $capabilities = array( WebDriverCapabilityType::BROWSER_NAME=>WebDriverBrowserType::FIREFOX );
            $this->driver = RemoteWebDriver::create('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', $capabilities, 5000);
        } catch (Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @AfterMethod
     */
    public function tearDown()
    {
        $this->driver->close();
    }

    public function testImageUpload()
    {
        $errorSnaps='';
        $myBrowserDriver    =   $this->driver;

        //open the url
        $myBrowserDriver->get($this->url);
        try{
            //get email field in login page
            $emailField =   $myBrowserDriver->findElement(WebDriverBy::id('email'));
            //check if the field is displayed
            if(!$emailField->isDisplayed()) {
                try {
                    $errorSnaps = $this->takeScreenshot();
                    $this->errorLogs[] = "The email input Element is not present, a screen-shot of the error has been placed here --> " . $errorSnaps;
                } catch (Exception $e){
                    $this->errorLogs[]  =   $e->getMessage();
                }
            }
        } catch (NoSuchElementException $nse){
            try {
                $errorSnaps = $this->TakeScreenshot();
                $this->errorLogs[] = "The email field on ".$this->driver->getCurrentURL()." not found , a screen-shot for the error has been placed here -->" . $errorSnaps;
            }catch (Exception $e){
                $this->errorLogs[]=$e->getMessage();
            }
         }
     }
```

php-webdrivers documentation recommends this way to initialize the browser drivers

```
$capabilities=array(
    \WebDriverCapabilityType::BROWSER_NAME=>WebDriverBrowserType::FIREFOX
);
$this->driver = RemoteWebDriver::create('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', $capabilities, 5000);
```

but does not provide a mechanism to init multiple browser drivers to run my tests with only single test file means considering the code above I have to make different copies for all those browsers and with only one line code difference means if i want to run the test above for chrome then i have to change the line from

```
$capabilities=array(\WebDriverCapabilityType::BROWSER_NAME=>WebDriverBrowserType::FIREFOX);
```

to

```
$capabilities=array(\WebDriverCapabilityType::BROWSER_NAME=>WebDriverBrowserType::CHROME);
```

and save that code with rest all the same code as above in a different file and run my test suit. As you can see this is not an optimal way for implementing my tests and for the sake of code re-usability.

---

I came across 2 options:

1. Pass argument from the terminal sending the browser name with parameter like `phpunit brName=chrome` and getting it via `$_SERVER['brName']`. I would still have to type in each time I want to run tests for any other browser.
2. I came across the `TestDecorator` class below on phpunit site which looked like a more conventional way to achieve what I am doing  but could not figure out how would I use it to run my tests.

**Where should I put my code so that it detects and runs it? Every time I try to run the below sample code it says no tests were executed. If i have sample test function below how could I run it 4 times using the testdecorator as base class?**

Sample Test:

```
public function sampleTest(){
    $this->assertTrue(TRUE);
}
```

Test Decorator class:

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Extensions/TestDecorator.php';

class PHPUnit_Extensions_RepeatedTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_TestDecorator
{
    private $timesRepeat = 1;

    public function __construct(PHPUnit_Framework_Test $test, $timesRepeat = 1)
    {
        parent::__construct($test);

        if (is_integer($timesRepeat) &&
            $timesRepeat >= 0) {
            $this->timesRepeat = $timesRepeat;
        }
    }

    public function count()
    {
        return $this->timesRepeat * $this->test->count();
    }

    public function run(PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult $result = NULL)
    {
        if ($result === NULL) {
            $result = $this->createResult();
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i < $this->timesRepeat && !$result->shouldStop(); $i++) {
            $this->test->run($result);
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: On the line: array(\WebDriverCapabilityType::BROWSER_NAME=>WebDriverBrowserType::FIREFOX);, is the "\" a syntax error?

Comment: it is a typo mistake writing it here

Comment: I tried to edit this into a more valuable post. As a sidenote, it was really hard to follow your code because you switch conventions every other line. You might consider picking some coding conventions and sticking with for the sake of readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not going in the right direction to implement this scenario I should not use the testdecorator class but a more good and easy approach would be.

1. Setting an environment variable via cmd-line/terminal like 
   `export BROWSER_REQUESTED=chrome` for (unix) and `set BROWSER_REQUESTED=chrome` for (windows),or you can create a `.sh` file with the following code 
   `export BROWSER_REQUESTED=chrome && phpunit` and run it via cmd-line.
2. Create a `BrowserFatory` class which listens to the environment variable and initiates the drivers for the browser type requested.

create as much `.sh` files as much browsers you need to run the test for, i have added the code below to be more descriptive.

**WebTest.php**

```
class WebTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @var \RemoteWebDriver
     */
    protected $driver;
    protected $url='http://example.com';
    protected $screenShotDirectoryPath  =   '/screenshots/';


    /**
     * @BeforeMethod
     */
    protected function setUp()
    {
        try{
            $this->driver = BrowserFactory::drivers();
        } catch (Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

**BrowserFactory.php**

```
class BrowserFactory
{
    public static function drivers()
    {
        switch ($_SERVER['BROWSER_REQUESTED']) {
            case 'chrome':
                return self::createChrome();
                break;
            case "ie":
                throw new Exception('Not implemented');
                break;

            case 'firefox':
            default:
                return self::createFirefox();
                break;
        }
    }

    public static function createChrome()
    {
        putenv("webdriver.chrome.driver=/path/to/chromedriver");

        $service = ChromeDriverService::createDefaultService();
        $service->start();

        return ChromeDriver::start(DesiredCapabilities::chrome(), $service);
    }

    public static function createFirefox()
    {
        // these are just constants defined in bootstrap.php
        $seleniumUrl = isset($_SERVER['JENKINS_URL']) ? TEST_ENV_SELENIUM_SERVER : LOCAL_ENV_SELENIUM_SERVER;

        return RemoteWebDriver::create(
            $seleniumUrl, DesiredCapabilities::firefox()
        );
    }
}
```

**command-line.sh**

```
export BROWSER_REQUESTED='chrome' && phpunit
```

Comment: nice work I was searching for the same thing from days and ended up here,. bingo

Comment: glad you could benefit from it